# What is the difference between Azure Metrics Explorer and Azure dashboard?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, metrics, azure-monitoring

If I would like to setup collection of custom metrics in Azure Insights and visualize some of them in a (nearly) real-time fashion and also see historic data aggregated, should I use Azure Metrics Explorer or Azure dashboard? What are they used for? What is the difference between them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Azure Metrics Explorer

- In an Azure metrics Explorer, we can select only **one resource** to view the metrics information.
- If we want to visualize **more than one resource** in **different subscription** metrics are not possible in a **single chart** of **Azure Metrics Explorer**.
- if you want to visualize metrics for more than one resource on **another subscription** you have to **create** a ***new chart***.
  [image]

Refer [Azure Metrics Started Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-getting-started)

#### Azure Dashboard

- Allow you to launch tasks for Day-to-Day **Operations**.
- **Customizable** based on Tasks, Projects, or User Roles.
- Monitor the **Performance, Availability**, and **Health** of the Resources.
  [image]
  By using **Dashboard** we can monitor all our resources on a single page.

Refer [Azure Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards)

> custom metrics in Azure Insights and visualize some of them in a (nearly) real-time fashion and also see historic data aggregated, should I use Azure Metrics Explorer or Azure dashboard

If you want to visualize **Single App Insights** Specific Data like (custom Metrics) you can choose **Azure Metrics**. Or if you want to visualize **more than one resource metric** you can choose the **Azure Dashboard**.

Comment: Thank you! By resource do you mean hosts or several kinds of metrics or both?

Comment: It is depending on what you want to view. Eg: if you want to view the custom metrics of app insights you can use the **Azure metrics Explorer**. or you want to view **both hosts and more metrics of other resources** like (app insights, VMs, app services, etc.,) you can use the **Dashboard**. In simple Dashboard is an organized view of **resources** and its **metrics**.